read pandas dataframe using skiprows and make two rows into column headers
While reading a xlsx file into pandas dataframe, I came into following situation: The column names were spread into multiple rows and actual data started from row 7. The Sample data shown as below.

Is there a way to combine the columns from multiple row in single columns, without doing manual hack? Well the data points are not duplicated, but it misses some string from the column names, resulting into columns that may appear as repeated.
This is what I have tried so far:
df = pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx",header = 6) and
df = pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx",skiprows = 6)
Expected output as follows:


Does this answer your question? Merge rows based on value (pandas to excel - xlsxwriter)

You could do this before reading

You can join MultiIndex values with parameter header in read_excel and list comprehension in next step:
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[6,7])
#alternative solution with skiprows
#df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=6, header=[0,1])

df.columns = [b if a.startswith('Unnamed:') else f'{a} {b}' for a, b in df.columns]


Thankyou, any workaround on how this work with csv files? Tried it with csv's and getting following error - pandas.errors.ParserError: Header rows must have an equal number of columns.

@Bits - What is different between csv and excel files? Is possible some column name in csv is missing? In another words if use df = pd.read_excel(file) instead df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[6,7]) and df = pd.read_csv(file) instead df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[6,7]) what is difference?

@Bits - Is possible create sample file with structure which fail? Because hard testing data from picture. Use dropbox or gdocs please. Thanks.

Hope it helps:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cmggbWjIFUYO_50NumfdiyyeXCiT-XKFrA-sARZ41ic/edit?usp=sharing

@Bits - Do you test sampel data? I try df = pd.read_csv('sample - Sheet1.csv', header=[6,7]) and df.columns = [b if a.startswith('Unnamed:') else f'{a} {b}' for a, b in df.columns] and solution working for me.
